# Can a firebase function (onWrite, onupdate, and undelete) be run without downloading data?

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

```
export const newNodeDetected = functions.database.ref('counter/likes/{postId}').onWrite((snapshot, context) => {

    const likeCount = snapshot.after.numChildren();
    const key = snapshot.after.key;
    snapshot.after.forEach(child => {
        console.log("[--] loop", child.child('{sd}'));
    });
    console.log("[--] true or false", snapshot.after.val());
    console.log("[--] value", likeCount);
    console.log("[--] key", snapshot.after.key);
    console.log(`[--] keystring questions ${key}`);
    database.ref(`posts/${key}/likeCount`).set(likeCount).catch(console.error);
});
```

if we don't include snapshot, we just had context only, will it still download data from that location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function isn't actually "downloading" anything.  All it does is write to the database.

The incoming snapshot isn't really a "download" at all.  That snapshot is going to be delivered to your function in all cases.  You can't tell Cloud Functions not to deliver it.  It's going to be entirely in memory when your function runs, so accessing it is going to be extremely fast.

Comment: ok thank you does it add up to the billing, when getting that data.

Comment: There is no additional billing for the size of the snapshot. You just pay the normal documented Cloud Functions costs.